# How can I send messages with 'format=flowed' with the notmuch message client?

Tags: email, emacs

I use the latest notmuch emacs client to compose and read my email. (They are sent via `msmtp`, and pulled with `mbsync`.)

I would like to have all my newly created messages to be formatted with `format=flowed`. All answers to this question I could find in the internet refer to Gnus.

Any ideas if it is possible to activate this feature with notmuch-message, or how to add it via elisp?

Comment: notmuch uses message-mode for composing, layering its own notmuch-message-mode on top, and uses message-mode for sending. The gnus or mm information on this is likely relevant. For example https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/GnusFormatFlowed

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but the emacswiki page is not any help to me. It only seems to discuss how to display `format=flowed` messages, and assumes that they are already sent the right way.

Comment: There's a section on displaying *and* composing flowed messages.

Comment: If you believe the solution to my question is on that page, why don't you present it here? Looking at the code, I find variables exclusively concerned with gnus (`gnus-article-mode-hook`, `gnus-treat-fill-long-lines`), and, what is worse, there are sentences like "The easiest way to deal with `format=flowed` is to avoid it." What is that supposed to mean??

Comment: See also https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/19296/retooling-fill-paragraph-to-append-trailing-spaces which asks how this could be achieved by enhancing `fill-paragraph`.

Comment: I wrote a new wiki page to help with this: https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FormatFlowed

Answer (score 2):

The following works:

```
 (require 'messages-are-flowing)
 (add-hook 'message-mode-hook #'messages-are-flowing-use-and-mark-hard-newlines)
```

There is no need to use Gnus to send mail.

Comment: Did you try this outside gnus?  I did, and [it doesn't work, for reasons which I attempted to explain](https://github.com/legoscia/messages-are-flowing/issues/2#issuecomment-333989987).

Comment: I use message mode, but I send my mails with msmtp (not Gnus). I guess using message mode amounts to "using it inside Gnus"?

Comment: I'm not sure - `message-mode` is defined in `gnus/message.el`, so it is technically part of Gnus, but I'm not sure why using it standalone would activate the functionality in `gnus/flow-fill.el`.  In fact, https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/GnusFormatFlowed even says "Just enabling ‘use-hard-newlines’ in ‘message-mode’ (as documented) is not enough to compose a flowed message and will most likely (as of 01/2011) kill all the formatting in your message."  But it's quite likely that's out-of-date - if you can verify that, it would be great if you could update the wiki page accordingly!

Comment: Could you give me a hint how I can verify it? Like, looking at the raw mail sent?

Comment: Sure, the raw mail sent should have a text MIME part with `Content-Type` including `format=flowed`, reflowable lines should end with a trailing space (denoting a soft newline) and should not start with a space or have spaces in between or after any `>` quoting prefix characters.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote some custom elisp to do this:

```
(defun as-format-as-flowed-text ()
  "Format the buffer as flowed text according to RFC 2646.
This ensures that appropriate lines should be terminated with a
single space, and that \"> \" quoting prefixes are replaced with
\">\".  Operates on the current region if active, otherwise on
the whole buffer."
  (interactive)
  (let ((start (if (use-region-p) (region-beginning) (point-min)))
        (end (if (use-region-p) (region-end) (point-max))))
    (save-excursion
      (goto-char start)
      ;; Ensure appropriate lines end with a space
      (while (re-search-forward "^\\(>+ ?\\)?\\S-.*\\S-$" end t)
        (replace-match "\\& " t))

      ;; Replace "> " quoting prefixes with ">"
      (goto-char start)
      (let ((eol)
            (eolm (make-marker)))
        (while (setq eol (re-search-forward "^>.*" end t))
          (set-marker eolm eol)
          (goto-char (match-beginning 0))
          (while (looking-at ">")
            (if (looking-at "> ")
                (replace-match ">")
              (forward-char)))
          (goto-char (marker-position eolm)))))))

(bind-key "M-s M-m" 'as-format-as-flowed-text)
```

(You can find [the permanent home for this here](https://github.com/aspiers/emacs/blob/23a22af991b35fcc7a96ac12847e1b8723d4c5c2/.emacs.d/init.d/as-editing.el#L29).  I'm pretty sure it could be written more elegantly; suggestions or even pull requests are very welcome.)

A few minutes after writing it, I discovered a certain amount of native support for `format=flowed` within gnus.  Unfortunately that functionality does not seem to be immediately reusable outside gnus at the time of writing.

I have just created https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FormatFlowed as a central portal in order to try to collect info on this topic in a single place.